# Objective performance measures for PCA?

Tags: pca, unsupervised-learning, model-evaluation

How can I measure how good my PCA was ?

Of course, it depends A LOT on context, or even maybe subjectivity sometimes.

But what objective measures can I use to measure how good my PCA was?
It doesn't make sense to use sum of squared distances from original data points to projected points, because by PCA'S definition, I already know that was minimized. Also, it does not make sense to measure variance, because I already know by PCA's definition that it was maximized.

Can you suggest other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are using your PCA for.

Are you using it to simplify your model for prediction? Then predict using a PCA model and a model without PCA (and use other methods for simplification, too, e.g., the Lasso), and check which one gives better predictions.

Or are you using it simply to explain and understand your data better? Then talk to experts about whether your factor loadings make sense. Peer review is a wonderful thing here, though it will be subjective and may be slow. If you publish an article with conclusions based on PCA, but it is never cited (or cited only to be ridiculed), then at least the community does not believe your PCA was any good.

Alternatively, collect another data sample and perform PCA again on that sample, checking whether factor loadings etc. are similar. This goes into test-retest reliability terrain.

Comment: Factors are from factor analysis. You probably mean PCs.